# Intento insertar registros con AJAX en php

Tags: php, ajax

Hola buenas soy nuevo en esto de ajax y estoy intentando hacer un insert con ajax para no estar todo el tiempo recargando la pagina, pero no se por que no me coge la función que tengo definida en funcion.php para usarla en ajax.php, tengo un main.js que es donde tengo definido el ajax recogiendo el valor del formulario donde dicho formulario esta en vista.php

**ajax.php**

```
switch ($action) {    
case 'post':
  insert_client();
    break;
```

}

**main.js**

```
  $('.insert').on('click', function () {
    var insert_prueba = $('#insert_prueba').serialize(),
    action='post'
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: insert_prueba,post,
        sucess: function (r) {
            console.log(r)
            if (r == 1) {
                alert("hola");
                
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**funcion.php**

```
function insert_client()
{

$conexion = conexionBBDD();

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$dni = $_POST['dni'];
$poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];


$insert = "INSERT into usuarios (Nombre,Apellidos, Telefono, Correo, Dirección, DNI, Población, Edad)
    VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidos',$telefono,'$correo','$direccion','$dni','$poblacion',$edad) ";
echo $insert;
$resultado = $conexion->query($insert);


if ($resultado) {
    echo '<script>alert("hola")</script>';
    // echo "<p>Se ha añadido $conexion->affected_rows registros con exito</p>";
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("error")</script>';

    echo "<p>Tuvimos problemas en la insercion, intentelo de nuevo mas tarde</p>";
}
}
```

**vista.php(donde tengo el formulario)**

```
<table>
    <h1 class="text-center">Insertar Clientes</h1>
    <form id="insert_prueba" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese sus apellidos">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="insertar" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 insert" value="Insertar clientes">
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿La consola devuelve algún error?

Comment: No devuelve ningún error

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar código del formulario.

Comment: Pareciera que `,post` esta demas aqui : `data: insert_prueba,post,` dejalo solo en `data:insert_prueba,`. `action=post` esta incluido en el form o lo deseas agregar al envio?

Comment: Estás mandando la petición a un archivo llamado `ajax.php`, como indicas aquí: `url: 'ajax.php'`, pero en la pregunta dices que el archivo que maneja la petición se llama `funcion.php`, si es así, la petición no está llegando.

Comment: en ajax.php estoy llamando a la funcion de insert_client() en funcion.php se supone que deberia cogerlo

Comment: @Triby ya esta puesto perdón jajaja

Comment: Muestra la parte de `ajax.php` donde recibes los datos. Dado que no pones retrocesos supongo que `ajax.php` está en el mismo archivo donde lanzas la petición ajax desde el cliente y que no es el mismo archivo, sino otro distinto. Por otra parte, depura con `alert` o `console.log` cada etapa para asegurarte de que el código sigue todo el recorrido, depura también lo que estás mandando en `data`

Comment: Desde el servidor, depura también con un `var_dump($_POST);`, la cuestión es depurar cada etapa y cada cosa. Si te sacas un doctorado en depuración te vas ahorrar horas, meses, años en tiempo perdido tratando de encontrar un problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano he tenido que borrar cosas del código pero con eso case que tenía en el switch si me funcionaba todo hasta que ese case del post no funciona

Comment: Pues eso, antes del `switch` haz un `var_dump($_POST);` y revisa la consola de Javascript para ver qué estás recibiendo realmente y cómo. Puede que la forma en que creas el valor de `$action` no sea correcta. Repito de nuevo, depurar, depurar, depurar y aprender a leer logs de errores. Te ahorrará años en tiempo perdido, te lo aseguro.

Answer (score 0):

En Javascript defines `action = 'post'`, pero no estás enviando esa variable en la petición AJAX.

```
$('.insert').on('click', function () {
    var insert_prueba = $('#insert_prueba').serialize(),
    action='post'
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: insert_prueba,post, // *******
        sucess: function (r) {
            console.log(r)
            if (r == 1) {
                alert("hola");
                
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Ten por seguro que `post` no se agrega al formulario, ni es un elemento válido en este código.

Lo más fácil sería agregar un campo oculto:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Insertar Clientes</h1>
<form id="insert_prueba" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  ?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese sus apellidos">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="insertar" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 insert" value="Insertar clientes">
</form>
```

Quedando tu función así:

```
$('.insert').on('click', function () {
    var insert_prueba = $('#insert_prueba').serialize(),
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: insert_prueba,
        sucess: function (r) {
            console.log(r)
            if (r == 1) {
                alert("hola");

            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

En PHP ya no tendrás problema para obtener la variable, con asignación ternaria:

```
$action = (isset($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : '';
// Aquí el switch
```

Por cierto, debes modificar la salida después de realizar la inserción, porque en `success` esperas `1` y estás enviando etiquetas `<script>` y no obtendrás el resultado esperado. Cambia todo esto:

```
if ($resultado) {
    echo '<script>alert("hola")</script>';
    // echo "<p>Se ha añadido $conexion->affected_rows registros con exito</p>";
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("error")</script>';

    echo "<p>Tuvimos problemas en la insercion, intentelo de nuevo mas tarde</p>";
}
```

Por una sola línea con operador ternario:

```
// Uno para inserción correcta, cero para error
echo ($resultado) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Yo no agregaría un campo oculto. En el `data`  que se envía vía Ajax se pueden agregar pares a mano. Por ejemplo: `action : 'post'` o cualquier otro. Dado que se está usando `serialize`, se puede agregar así: **`var insert_prueba = $('#insert_prueba').serialize()+"&action=post";`** así el código queda más libre y se evitan elementos ocultos en el HTML.

Comment: @A.Cedano, por eso puse que `lo más fácil sería...`. Yo prefiero _FormData_ en lugar de serializar, porque te permite agregar datos sin mayor problema. Ya que viste dónde está el error, eres bienvenido si quieres colaborar con otra respuesta mejor elaborada.

Comment: No suelo responder cuando hay respuestas bien encaminadas. La intención del comentario es que mejores la respuesta, si quieres. En el código original OP tiene una solución parecida a lo que comento, sólo que no agrega bien el parámetro `action`, me parece que recomendarle un campo oculto para resolver algo que puede resolverse con una simple concatenación incita a malas prácticas y además se aleja de su intención original.

Comment: ¿Por qué es mala práctica agregar un campo oculto? Yo suelo incluir la acción de esta forma o, en su defecto, como parámetro en la URL. ¿Tienes alguna referencia al respecto? Me gustaría leerla para saber qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Es una mala práctica porque no se necesita, porque puedes prescindir de ello, porque no hace falta recargar el código para algo que puedes resolver simplemente con esto: `+"&action=post"` en el código JS, porque haces el código más dependiente metiendo en el HTML algo que pertenece a la lógica de tu programa. Imaginemos un programa grande con varios miles de formulario donde pusiste el `action` en un campo oculto del HTML. Si mañana hay algún cambio tendrás que ir a los miles de formularios a modificar tus campos ocultos. Si lo centralizas en el código JS ese cambio será más fácil.

Comment: Sin una referencia de por medio y basados en opiniones, yo creo que la mala práctica es usar una cadena en lugar de un elemento de formulario que se va a recibir por `$_POST` y, ampliando un poco mi forma de verlo, siempre uso el mismo formulario para insertar o actualizar, aplicando algunos pequeños cambios como la acción y desactivando cosas que no deben modificarse. Por eso es preciso que la acción esté definida en el formulario y no se agregue concatenando en una función.

Comment: `serialize()` concatena de todos modos y el código está basado en esa función, por lo tanto, lo más simple para este caso es concatenar, tampoco hay problema en ello (el mismo campo oculto que agregues terminará siendo una cadena). Cuando no se usa `serialize()` yo prefiero crear un objeto para pasarlo en `data`, pero si está usando `serialize()` no hay por qué recurrir a complicaciones, se concatena el `action` y listo, y el DOM queda más independiente y menos cargado.

Comment: @A.Cedano, entiendo tu punto, pero ¿qué pasaría si decide usar el mismo formulario para actualizar? Sería más sencillo usar ese campo oculto cambiando _post_ por _edit_ y no tiene que tocar código en javascript.

Comment: @Triby la solución que me has pasado me ha venido de perlas

Comment: muchas gracias a los dos y @A.Cedano intentare también hacerlo como me has recomendado y así veo los dos punto de vista, de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: otra pregunta, para  utilizar ajax hace falta json en algun momento? lo pregiunto por que siguiendo antes un proyecto anterior de un curso con array y ajax se estaba utilizando

Comment: @SergioMartinez JSON no es obligatorio, pero se usa mucho para las respuestas Ajax porque es ligero y te permite mandar datos estructurados mucho más fáciles de analizar o de leer. Desde el servidor puedes responder también con html o con text, pero JSON es lo más ligero, ten en cuenta que hay consumo de recursos, de red, etc en las peticiones Ajax, por lo que mientras más ligera sea la respuesta mejor. Imagina una tabla, es más ligero responder un JSON que responder toda la tabla construida en html en el servidor.

Comment: Triby aunque se use el mismo formulario para distintas operaciones, siempre es más sencillo indicar el action en el código JS. De todos modos, los datos tienen que recogerse en JS, habrá que poner código de escucha en JS sobre los eventos del DOM. Además, los datos que se recogen para un Create, no suelen ser los mismos que para un Update. En el form podría haber diferentes botones por ejemplo y tomar de ellos la acción a ejecutar según el botón que haya sido presionado.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias